# Correct Amazon MWS flow for item with existing ASIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm getting started with Amazon MWS and I can't seem to see any real information on the correct flow for listing an item as an existing ASIN. Let's say for example I am selling a "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether". I do an initial lookup using "listMatchingProducts" and find that my item already exists with the ASIN "B000IDSLOG". What is the next stage in the process?. All the documentation talks about the fact that the product feed is intended to match our SKU to the Amazon ASIN but i've not seen any definitive information to suggest how this actually works - especially in the scenario where you already know the ASIN you wish to use.

Ideally i'm interested in seeing the correct flow for each scenario (existing product for search found/not found) in terms of what API calls should be made in what order.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems in the case of adding a product with an existing ASIN you can actually send a very basic XML request such as this, making sure to include the ASIN:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>UNIQUE-TO-ME-1234</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B000A0S46M</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Essentially though, from what i've read elsewhere it seems that Amazon will attempt to match a product to an existing ASIN according to the data within the _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ feed even if an ASIN isn't provided. It will use elements such as title, manufacturer, brand, and other product specific information to compare that to their catalog and determine if it is an existing item or a new one to be added. If you do know it already has an ASIN though you can provide a very simple XML feed as shown above.

Comment: This is correct. However, I wonder if there is a way to send the price and inventory along with this feed? Is that ever supported? Or we must send subsequent feeds for price and inventory?

Comment: @SameersJaved no you need to send a separate feed ( _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_ ) to update price and another ( _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_ ) for inventory stock

Comment: I m able to add new items to amazon, update their prices and quantity. But unable to update any other filed i.e Platinum Keywords. How I will be able to do it.

Answer (score 23):

The process of listing an item on Amazon is actually very similar for existing ASINs and new ones.

Listing items can consist of these steps:

1. Call `SubmitFeed()` to send a `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_` feed

   - is mandatory in all cases. You can omit product details if you're adding your listing to an existing item. If you list new products, this feed must be successfully processed before sending any other feed for those same item(s), I'm not sure if the same is true for existing products.
2. Call `SubmitFeed()` to send a `_POST_PRODUCT_RELATIONSHIP_DATA_` feed

   - This step can be skipped for existing products or products without variants or other parent/child relations
3. Call `SubmitFeed()` to send a `_POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_` feed

   - This step can be skipped for existing products. Amazon is currently in the process of making images mandatory, so for new products or products currently not showing an image, you really should submit at least one image
4. Call `SubmitFeed()` to send a `_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_` feed

   - is mandatory in all cases
5. Call `SubmitFeed()` to send a `_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_` feed

   - is mandatory in all cases
6. Call `SubmitFeed()` to send a `_POST_PRODUCT_OVERRIDES_DATA_` feed

   - is optional, and only used for items that have special shipping rates applied (e.g. expedited products)

More information on feeds is available on the [Amazon Developer Documentation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/index.html) website and in  [Selling on Amazon: Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf)

Comment: For sending Stock-Data, use the _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_ Type. _POST_PRODUCT_AVAILABILITY_DATA is wrong...

Comment: It's also possible to combine steps 4 and 5 using a `_POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA_` feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use flat file template from amazon to load your feeds to marketplace with your seller account credentials using marketplace web service.

Use 'inventory loader' file type template that will override the existing items or create new if doesn't exists.

You can define 'ASIN-Hint' fields/column in file for the items those already exists over marketplace as your case is.

Idea behind is that amazon matches the provided ASIN value with feed with the already existed product detail and synch information accordingly.

Try uploading your product without ASIN-Hint and see process report you will get a good idea then.

You may also refer http://prashantpandeytech.blogspot.in/2015/03/mws-amazon-marketplace-web-service-api.html for step wise implementation