# Amazon Marketplace Web Service (MWS) - add my offer to an existing product

Tags: api, amazon-mws

On Amazon Marketplace, there can be multiple offers from different sellers on a single product. So for example Duracell Coppertop AA Batteries are sold by 110 different merchants.

What I need to do is programmatically add my own offer to specific product, join those other sellers offering it.

I know ASIN's of the products I need to place offers to.

The question is what are the steps to place another offer to an existing product through Amazon API.

I think I should upload a Flat File though MWS, but unable to find anywhere what should be the exact format to comply with the above requirement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are:

- Manually add items through the Seller Central browser interface
- Use flat files to upload your data. I have no experience with this, but look at _POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_ and _POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_ .
- Use XML feeds. The workflow is described here: [Amazon MWS workflow (XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423769/correct-amazon-mws-flow-for-item-with-existing-asin/17434970#17434970)