# Amazon Marketplace API ProductImage Feed unexpected element error while parsing xml

Tags: java, xml, xsd, amazon-mws

I'm working with amazon mws feed api in java and I'm having some problem while sending a ProductImage feed to amazon.

This is the xml I'm sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProductImage>
    <SKU>ABCDORD0001</SKU>
    <ImageType>Main</ImageType>
    <ImageLocation>http://vocearancio.ingdirect.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bici-1.jpeg</ImageLocation>
</ProductImage>
```

And this is the web service response (only the interesting part):

```
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 2, Column 15: Found unexpected element &apos;ProductImage&apos; while parsing the start of this &apos;AmazonEnvelope&apos; document. Children of this element will be ignored by the parser..</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
```

I don't understand why he ignores the ProductImage tag, I'm following an example in the documentation and it should be fine.
I'm sending the feed with `request.setFeedType("_POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_");`
Is it because I'm missing the Envelope part? I thought the java API did that, I had no problem with other feeds (even tough the product doesn't show in the sellecentral inventory).

This was my POST_PRODUCT_DATA feed (the fist that I should be sending, not the one above) that returned with no errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Product>
    <SKU>ABCDORD0001</SKU>
    <LaunchDate>2014-11-10T00:00:00.000+01:00</LaunchDate>
    <ReleaseDate>2014-11-10T00:00:00.000+01:00</ReleaseDate>
    <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
    </Condition>
    <DescriptionData>
        <Title>titolo_articolo</Title>
        <Brand>brand_item</Brand>
        <Description>descrizione_articolo_dett</Description>
        <ItemType>sotto_categoria</ItemType>
    </DescriptionData>
    <ProductData>
        <Sports></Sports>
    </ProductData>
</Product>
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing the amazon-envelope part, here is an example of the correct xml I now send to the webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AmazonEnvelope>
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A2UAUVMGTII0KR</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>ABCDORD0005</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ISBN</Type>
                <Value>9788478888566</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <LaunchDate>2014-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00</LaunchDate>
            <ReleaseDate>2014-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00</ReleaseDate>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</Title>
                <Brand>brand_item</Brand>
                <Description>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series, written by J. K. Rowling.</Description>
                <Manufacturer>J. K. Rowling</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>sotto_categoria</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Sports></Sports>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

And this works just fine, got no returning errors, just note that it takes almost 1 minute for the product to shop up in the seller central, and 10 more minutes for it to be processed and become active. ***Also, the element StandardProductID is really important, if you don't provide the correct code you will get a missing key error in return.***

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're sending your image feed using the `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_` SubmitFeed consant.

Instead, you need to send your images using the `_POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_` constant. There is a description of the [workflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17434970/2097290). Look at the [Selling on Amazon, Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf) for details on the feed's required contents. It features an example feed on pages 47/48.

Comment: I'm using the right feed type (_POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_), I edited the question.