# How to List Product on Existing Product Page

Tags: api, amazon-mws

Every Amazon product page has a 'buy box,' but customers can also buy from other third party sellers in the 'other sellers' column on the right. How do I list my product there via the MWS API?

The documentation seems to show how to add an entirely new product to Amazon MWS via the API, but not how to add a product to an existing page with the same ASIN (and specify things like inventory count too).

I'm trying to figure out what the XML Feed would look too. Much appreciation if anyone knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, the workflows are the same for existing and new items. This SO question covers it in detail: [Correct Amazon MWS flow for item with existing ASIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423769/correct-amazon-mws-flow-for-item-with-existing-asin)