# why Current Status of Listings is inactive amazon seller account

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have created a seller account and successfully created an item, but after 15 minutes it is not showing to buy on amazon portal.

When we check Account info, then

> Current Status of Listings: Inactive (Listings not available for sale on Amazon)

Why is current status of listing inactive?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MWS, you most probably did not complete the [MWS workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423769/correct-amazon-mws-flow-for-item-with-existing-asin/17434970#17434970): products with missing pricing information or missing inventory data will not go live on Amazon. If the item is complete, you need to check your account for anything that may block sales totally - different Amazon sites have different requirements for sellers which may or may not have met yet.