# how can i add produts to amazon sellers account by MWS xml feed

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am trying to add product by xml feed but still unable to add that. I tried it through amazon scratch pad and its showing status complete but when i am checking in seller account there it is not showing. You can also check below  xml code which i am trying to submit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_SELLER_354577</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>1Z-500ABR-FLAT</SKU>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <LaunchDate>2005-07-26T00:00:01</LaunchDate>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Lyric 500 tc Queen Flat Sheet, Ivory</Title>
                <Brand>Peacock Alley</Brand>
                <Description>Lyric sheeting by Peacock Alley is the epitome of simple and classic elegance. The flat sheets
    and pillowcases feature a double row of hemstitching. The fitted sheets fit mattresses up to 21 inches deep.
    The sheets are shown at left with tone on tone monogramming, please call for monogramming details and prices.
    Please note, gift wrapping and overnight shipping are not available for this style.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>made in Italy</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>500 thread count</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>plain weave (percale)</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>100% Egyptian cotton</BulletPoint>
                <Manufacturer>Peacock Alley</Manufacturer>
                <SearchTerms>bedding</SearchTerms>
                <SearchTerms>Sheets</SearchTerms>
                <ItemType>flat-sheets</ItemType>
                <IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
                <IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
                <RecommendedBrowseNode>60583031</RecommendedBrowseNode>
                <RecommendedBrowseNode>60576021</RecommendedBrowseNode>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
            <Home>
            <Parentage>variation-parent</Parentage>
            <VariationData>
            <VariationTheme>Size-Color</VariationTheme>
            </VariationData>
            <Material>cotton</Material>
            <ThreadCount>500</ThreadCount>
            </Home>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML does not validate against my XSDs. There are two things I had to change in order to get it to validate:

1. change "amznenvelope.xsd" to "amzn-envelope.xsd" in the XML header
2. change the structure of `<ProductData>`

.

```
...
<ProductData>
    <Home>
        <ProductType>
            <BedAndBath>
                <Material>cotton</Material>
                <ThreadCount>500</ThreadCount>      
                <VariationData>
                    <VariationTheme>Size-Color</VariationTheme>
                </VariationData>        
            </BedAndBath>
        </ProductType>
        <Parentage>variation-parent</Parentage>
    </Home>
</ProductData>
....
```

Please note that submitting a single feed will *not* be enough to successfully create a new product on Amazon. [Creating items on Amazon using XML workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423769/correct-amazon-mws-flow-for-item-with-existing-asin/17434970#17434970).

Answer (score 0):

Do not user perge and replace option with true value , if you place true then it will delete all product from amazon sellers account.

```
<PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
```