# Amazon xml feed with mws api using PHP Client Library

Tags: php, xml, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Hello I am new to Amazon API,
I want to list my products using MWS API product feed from my own HTML application.I have downloaded Developer Resources from here

https://developer.amazonservices.com/api.html?group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest

1.Edited **".config.inc.php"** from **\src\MarketplaceWebService\Samples**

2.Changed **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and MERCHANT_ID**

3.Edited **SubmitFeedSample.php** file and followed instructions and removed comments accordingly and changed method to **_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_**

4.Followed the tutorial present in **"Selling on Amazon Guide to XML"** to Generate this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>mymerchantid</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
<SKU>720656549</SKU>
<DescriptionData>
<Title>GIRLS S/S PRINTED COTTON AND PLITED FROCK WITH CONTRAST FRONT BELT AND BOW</Title>
<Brand>mybrand</Brand>
<Description>The Girls Racer Back Neck Tie up Tunic from Oye is the perfect choice to dress your little girl while heading out for the day.It is made of soft and pliable material, which ensures to keep her fresh and comfortable throughout the day.Pair this dress with cute ballerinas and matching hair accessories to complete the casual look.</Description>
<BulletPoint>Made in India</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>500 thread count</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>plain weave (percale)</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>100% Egyptian cotton</BulletPoint>
<Manufacturer>mybrand</Manufacturer>
<SearchTerms>clothes</SearchTerms>
<SearchTerms>baby girl</SearchTerms>
<ItemType>Girls</ItemType>
<IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
<IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
</DescriptionData>
<ProductData>
<Home>
<Parentage>variation-parent</Parentage>
<VariationData>
<VariationTheme>Size-Color</VariationTheme>
</VariationData>
<Material>cotton</Material>
<ThreadCount>500</ThreadCount>
</Home>
</ProductData>
</Product>
</Message>
<Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

5.Tested this XML in **MWS Scratchpad** and the result is

```
 Response (200)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SubmitFeedResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
<SubmitFeedResult>
  <FeedSubmissionInfo>
    <FeedSubmissionId>50081******</FeedSubmissionId>
    <FeedType>_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_</FeedType>
    <SubmittedDate>*********</SubmittedDate>
    <FeedProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</FeedProcessingStatus>
  </FeedSubmissionInfo>
</SubmitFeedResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>*****************</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</SubmitFeedResponse>
```

6.Added this XML code in **"SubmitFeedSample.php"** on **$feed** variable(line 99)

7.Uploaded all files of **"PHP Client Library"** on my hostgator server

8.Browsed to the file in firefox

9.In firefox it shows **"FeedProcessingStatus SUBMITTED"** in service response.

But after doing all this I am unable to see product in my "Manage Inventory" on seller central account.

and last thing how to use **"_POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_"** and its xml(as shown in XML guide) in **SubmitFeedSample.php** simultaneously with **"_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_"**

Please help as their are no simple tutorials or videos to demonstrate the exact process.

Comment: if this helps https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2913&start=0&tstart=0&sortBy=date

Comment: Hi there i found this XSDs examples on git if that helps https://github.com/dmichael/amazon-mws/tree/master/examples/xsd

Comment: @keyur many of those XSD files are too old and will not be valid. and or  might not be valid for the specific merchant account. Get the XSD files directly inside the seller central account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Check if the feeds you submitted actually get processed successfully
2. As a minimum, you need to send 3 feeds: product data, pricing and stock quantities. After those three feeds are processed, the items will show up in Seller Central. More details here: [Correct Amazon MWS flow for item with existing ASIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423769/correct-amazon-mws-flow-for-item-with-existing-asin/17434970#17434970)

Answer (score 0):

I m also new to amazon API and using the following schema.
And It's working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
        <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>YOUR_MERCHANT_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
        </Header>
        <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
        <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace><Message>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                <Product>
                <SKU>25075-9x12</SKU>
                <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B01MCR4YC5</Value>
                </StandardProductID>
                <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
                <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Anam Black Large Rug</Title>
                <Brand>Alliyah Rugs</Brand>
                <Description>
The Alliyah Collection offers high quality, value and integrity that seems to been lost in recent times by most manufactures. The Anam Black Large Rug is made of first grade New-Zealand blend wool which is Hand washed, Hand carved and Hand finished. The entire collection is 100% Handmade.</Description>
                <ItemType>New</ItemType>
                </DescriptionData>
                </Product>
                </Message></AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: But is your product getting added to your inventory and not as a draft?

Comment: Yes, adding to inventory.

Comment: I am using almost same XML file. But my product always gets saved as draft. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: I did this few years ago and recently not having access to that system. But I did face this issue. It's was adding a record at all and after some fixing it starts working.
Do you have enough rights to add the record?

Comment: You are using scratchpad?

Comment: No I am using Client libraries(Java) provided by Amazon.  The product gets added in the draft. [Here is the detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500381/how-to-add-product-directly-to-the-inventory-using-submitfeed-amazon-mws-api).

Comment: Sorry, my above comment is not clear and I'm not able to edit that. So writing again here.
I did this few years ago and recently not having access to that system. But I did not face this issue. It's was not adding record at all and after some fixing it starts working. Do you have enough rights to add the record?
Please use https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html to test your feed. It's environment independent .