# Amazon MWS client libraries

Tags: amazon-mws

I am working in salesforce domain and trying to create products in Amazon seller account using product feed api. But I am not sure how do I create a perfect xml feed file for product belongs to category jewelry . Can I use MWS client library for that or There is a different and better way to accomplish that ? Please suggest !
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The MWS client libraries available for download on the Amazon developer site will help you interacting with the API, but are of no help creating suitable XML feeds.

You will need to do the following:

- create various XML feeds
- send feeds to Amazon make sure feeds are accepted
- wait for processing results
- notify your users and/or developers of errors / success

The client library will only help you with step 2 and 3. More information on the workflow is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17434970/2097290

Answer (score 0):

You can find client libraries for Java, C# and PHP.
https://developer.amazonservices.com/tools